# Blogger IFRAME reciveing URL_argument from URL

Tags: javascript, blogs, blogger, blogspot

Is it possible to have a page (or post) in the **BLOGGER** platform that works similar to this:

```
blog.blogspot.com/a.html?url=http://google.com/
```

And it would embed in an **IFRAME** the argument (http://google.com/)

I already have the code for the IFRAME, but it's static:

```
<iframe src ="http://google.com/" width="100%" height="300">
<p>Your browser does not support iframes.</p>
</iframe>
```

Ps.: My real objective is to get 2 arguments (one for the URL and another for the return page), but If someone helps me with 1 argument, I think I can adapt it for several arguments.

Thnx in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Done.
I tested it in bloger and it does work.

```
<script>

function getQueryVariable(variable) { 
  var query = window.location.search.substring(1); 
  var vars = query.split("&"); 
  for (var i=0;i<vars.length;i++) { 
    var pair = vars[i].split("="); 
    if (pair[0] == variable) { 
      return pair[1]; 
    } 
  } 
} 
</script>

<script>
document.write('<iframe src ="'+ getQueryVariable("url") + '" width="100%" height="300"><p>Your browser does not support iframes.</p></iframe>')
</script>
```

Hope this helps

Answer (score 1):

You just need to get the `window.location.href` string and then parse out the relevant parts.  For an example on how to do the parsing, see [this tutorial](http://www.htmlgoodies.com/beyond/javascript/article.php/3471111).

Answer (score 0):

you have to use javascript todo so

Comment: could you please give me some examples? (or links... or man pages.. something)